# Erro de Espaçamento

Tags: php, html

Bom é o seguinte, eu estou a desenvolver um site para um clube de futebol, mas estou com um problema.

Eu pretendia mostrar 4 jogadores de cada tipo por linha, ou seja na primeira linha mostrava no máximo 4 defesas, e se houvesse mais defesas no bd ia para a segunda linha no template.

Estou com o problema que não consigo fazer isso, já tentei dar  mas o que acontece é que vai tudo para baixo, em vez de ir só o x que eu quero.

Abaixo demonstra o link do que estou a falar:

http://afdtorre.pt/plantel_juniores.php

Meu Código:

```
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center"><table width="60%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="plantel">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                  <?php
                  $sql0 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from plant_juniores WHERE ordposicao='0'");

                  while($array0 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql0)){
                  ?>

                    <td width="30"><?php echo $array0["numero"]; ?></td>

                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array0["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array0["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Guarda-Redes</td>
                    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
                    <?php
                  }
                    while($array0 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql0)){
                    ?>
                    <td width="30"><?php echo $array0["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array0["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array0["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Guarda-Redes</td>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <?php

                  $sql1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from plant_juniores WHERE ordposicao='1'");

                  while($array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){

                  ?>

                    <td><?php echo $array1["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array1["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array1["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Defesa</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <?php
                  }
                    while($array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
                    ?>


                    <td><?php echo $array1["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array1["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array1["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Defesa</td>
                   <?php 
    }
  ?>



                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <?php

                  $sql2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from plant_juniores WHERE ordposicao='2'");

                  while($array2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){

                  ?>

                    <td><?php echo $array2["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array2["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array2["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Médio</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                    <?php

                  }

                  while($array2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
                  ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array2["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array2["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array2["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Médio</td>

                    <?php

                  }

                  ?>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <?php
              $sql3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from plant_juniores WHERE ordposicao='3'");

                  while($array3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)){

                  ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array3["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array3["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array3["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Avançado</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <?php
                  }
                    while($array3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)){

                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array3["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array3["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array3["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Avançado</td>
                    <?php

                    }
                    ?>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                  <?php
              $sql4 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from plant_juniores WHERE ordposicao='4'");

                  while($array4 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql4)){

                  ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array4["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array4["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array4["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Treinador</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <?php
                  }
                    while($array4 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql4)){

                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array4["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array4["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array4["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Treinador</td>
                    <?php

                    }
                    ?>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                  <?php
              $sql5 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from plant_juniores WHERE ordposicao='5'");

                  while($array5 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql5)){

                  ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array5["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array5["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array5["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Treinador-Adjunto</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <?php
                  }
                    while($array5 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql5)){

                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $array5["numero"]; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="admin/<?php echo $array5["foto"]; ?><width="50" height="67" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $array5["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td>Treinador-Adjunto</td>
                    <?php

                    }
                    ?>
                  </tr>


                </tbody>
              </table></td>
```

Como poderei fazer para apenas mostrar 4 defesas por cada "linha" e não mostrar aquele tanto de defesas numa linha só?

Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite. Tente fazer o controle via css. De um tamanho para o tr em seguida coloque tamanho no td. Assim fazendo caber apenas 4 td por linha no tr. Caso o mesmo funcionaria com div.